# regression model assumption

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, regression

I try to check whether my regression model is follow regression assumption or not? for that I did below python code but response is error. can someone explain how it wrong

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
reg = LinearRegression()
reg = reg.fit(x_train,y_train)
reg.score(x_test,y_test)
```

> `**0.9071005491012577**`

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Res=reg.resid()
sm.qqplot(Res,fit=True,line='45')
Plt.show()
```

Then i got below error.

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         5 #plt.title("Model1 Residuals Probability Plot")
>         6 
>   ----> 7 Res=reg.resid()
>         8 Fig=sm.qqplot(Res,fit=True,line='45')
>         9 Plt.show()
>
> AttributeError: 'LinearRegression' object has no attribute 'resid'

Comment: Please, elaborate your question. What do you mean with: "whether my regression model is follow regression assumption or not" ?

Comment: I want draw qq plot for regression to check regression assumption are violate or not? for that i run above code but its give error.. what is reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message, sklearn's `LinearRegression()` objects have no `.resid` attribute.

You must calcualate residuals manually: it's the difference between actual y values `y_train` and predicted values `reg.predict(X_train)`. Once you get those, you can run `sm.qqplot()`.

NB: `Plt.show()` returns error. Change it with: `plt.show()`

Comment: Thanks Leevo. i did changes and i got a qq plot.